# Why isn't my Dojo ContentPane resolving its promise after loading content?

Tags: javascript, dojo, promise, dijit.layout

I'm struggling to fix bugs in a relatively old app that was written for an old version of Dojo, never worked quite right even then, and is now running on Dojo 1.10. Some of the application logic is not quite right for current Dojo paradigms, but some of it seems right to me and I can't figure out why it's not working as expected.

There is a custom widget based on `dijit.layout.ContentPane`. None of the added methods seem to clobber the originals and only serve to wire up some scroll events to other widgets via topics. There is also a topic that can trigger a change of address in the ContentPane.

The relevant bits look something like this:

```
// The widget is initially setup declarative markup
var contentPaneWidget = registry.byId("<content_pane_id>");

// This subscribe is actually part of the custom widget code, but
// the topic subscription and resulting set() work, so I don't think
// where this is run is relevant to the question
topic.subscribe("navEvent", function(url) {
    contentPaneWidget.set("href", url).then(function() {
        topic.publish("navComplete", url);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("Navigation error:", err);
    });
});

// This topic subscription in another widget should get fired after
// content loads in the ContentPane based widget 
topic.subscribe("navComplete", function(url) {
    console.log("Navigation finished:",  url);
});

// Test the chain ov events by firing off a new URL to the nav topic
topic.publish("navEvent", "<new_content_url>");
```

The content loads properly. The URL is parsed and loaded, and the content pane updates with the downloaded content. **The trouble is the `.then()` function never fires** and hence the *navComplete* topic is never activated. The funny thing is it isn't just the succeed function that doesn't fire, the error function doesn't fire either. The promise is just left open.

If I manually resolve the promise (by either adding `.resolve()` onto the end of the chain or calling `contentPaneWidget.onLoadDeferred.resolve()` later in the code or manually from the console) then everything fires off as expected. [As documented](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_layout_ContentPane_onLoadDeferred) `set("href", ...)` is returning a promise, the promise is just never resolved after the network operation and content rendering is finished.

Is this incorrect usage? Is there a bug in Dojo? Or am I hunting for some other gremlin in this apps code?

Comment: The resolve of the deferred in within a try/catch. I guess the content you are loading fires a JS error and the error is swalloed by the try catch so you don't see anything

Comment: @ben Cha-ching we have a winner! The entire block of code in the app surrounding the `set('href', ...)` was wrapped in a try statement that was interfering with whatever Dojo was doing. I removed the try massive try block and replaced it with just wrapping the two lines that are known to throw exceptions and the app suddenly has all it's topic channels running again! Can you make a note possible try/accept interaction problems into  an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great that it helped! `try/catch` is more of a problem than a solution in most of the case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The resolve of the deferred in within a `try/catch`.
See https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/layout/ContentPane.js#L440

I guess the content you are loading fires a JS error and this error is swalloed by the `try/catch` thus you don't see anything happening...